# Can background images have a maximum size

Tags: html, css

I have an element that fills the entire page, with a background image that fits inside it:

```css
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;

background: url(path/to/image.jpg);
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
```

If the image is larger than the screen, it gets nicely shrunk to fit in the window.  However, if the image is smaller than the screen, it gets expanded. I don't want the background image to be expanded.

I know I can solve this with JavaScript by getting the size of the image and adjusting the CSS of the container - but I was just wondering if there is a CSS-only solution - something like a `max-background-height` attribute.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without js unless you max out the element's height as well

Comment: You could probably achieve the effect with media queries.

Comment: @jacob - could you give an example?  Or explain further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
@media only screen
    and (min-width: 1280px /* largest size in px where you want the image to stop expanding */) {
        background-size: 1280px 798px;
        /* or whatever the original size of your image is */
    }
```

Basically the idea is to give the image a fixed sized (its original, largest size it can be without becoming distorted) whenever the window is resized past a specified width.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  As a caveat for later generations though, this assumes one knows the size of the image before the page is generated (ie: dynamically).  This won't work with images of unknown size.